# ios 8 swift orientation change : Keyboard frame does not display correctly

Tags: swift, ios8, keyboard

My app consist of both landscape as well as portrait orientation.In portrait screen if hit textfield the portrait dimensional keyboard apperars & my next screen is landscape where in on textfield landscpae dimensional keyboard apperas.But if I back to again portrait screen then on textfield hit I get landscape dimensional keyboard.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug when having view controllers that support different screen orientations. A solution that worked for me was by setting manually screen orientation to portrait just before dismissing the landscape view controller by using this:

```
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: this doesn't work .I wrote  this UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation") in viewDidDisappear of landscape viewcontroller.but same problem keyboard is of landscape dimensional only

Comment: Are you using NavigationController ? As I said you have to set orientation BEFORE dismissing view controller and not neither in viewDidDisappear even nor viewWillDisappear

Comment: yes i have used navigation controller.I tried to set orientation in back btn clicked of landscape controller.But it doesnt work.It changes the orientation of screen to landscape of previous one which is in portrait orientation.